# how to open text file in android using a kind of file Chooser or openfiledialog like in C# etc

Tags: java, android, file-upload, openfiledialog

I want user to choose his desired *text file.*

My code:

```
File file = new File("mytextfile.txt");
System.out.println("This is your file");
System.out.println(file);
FileInputStream fin = null;


try {
    fin = new FileInputStream(file);
    System.out.println(fin);        
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Why this is not working?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to read the contents of the file? If so you need to use FileReader.

Comment: What do you mean by "open text file" Do you want to open the file in an APP, do you want to open it in Java, do you want to read its content into a string, etc...? This question is not clear enough!

Comment: i want to open file in emulator. also i want to read its contents in string and then split the string using delimiters..

Comment: i need a kind of file explorer only for text files..